# Load balanced Fiware Orion

Tags: nginx, supervisord, fiware-orion

I just created a dockerized load balanced version of OCB using Nginx and supervisord running separate instances of Orion balanced by Nginx. Only for testing purposes.

My question is if I use this approach, would I have some troubles with TIMEINTERVAL subscriptions? (I don't want 'n' notifications for each OCB process).

Any help will be sure appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Current Orion version (0.23.0) works in the following way: at creation time, the ONTIMEINTERVAL subscribeContext is dispatched by the LB to one of the CB nodes, which creates a permantent thread in charge of sending notification messages at the notification frequency.

However, there are two kind of problems:

- If the client wants to cancel the subscription sending unsubscribeContext, that request could be recived by a CB *not* managing the subscription. Thus, the operation may result in the subscription being deleted from DB, but the notification continues being sent.
- Let's consider that in a given moment CB1 managed subscriptions S1 and S2 and CB2 managed S3 and S4. Let's consider that CB2 fails and that it is restarted. The CB2 will "see" four subscription (S1, S2, S3 and S4) at starting time, thus 4 threads are created and the final result is that S3 and S4 notifications are duplicated (being sent at the same time by CB1 and CB2).

Thus, in sum ONTIMEINTERVAL subscription are discouraged in HA and/or horizontal scaling scenarios. However, note that all use cases based on ONTIMEINTERVAL can be "reversed" running a queryContext-based polling at the same frequency at the notification receptor, so it doesn't use to be a big problem.

**EDIT**: ONTIMEINTERVAL subscription [were removed in Orion 1.0.0](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/deprecated/index.html). ONTIMEINTERVAL subscriptions had several problems (as the ones described in the above answer). Actually, they aren't really needed, as any use case based on ONTIMEINTERVAL notification can be converted to an equivalent use case in which the receptor runs queryContext at the same frequency (and taking advantage of the features of queryContext, such as pagination or filtering)

Comment: Thanks @fgalan. Only one question: What happens (in the same scenario) if all CB shares the same mongo database?

Comment: Except for the ONTIMEINTERVAL issues described in the answer post above, Orion is prepared to run in multi-node scenarios which share the same Mongo database.

Comment: Answer edited to add extra info regarding ONTIMEINTERVAL removal from Orion 1.0.0